# Why is jquery's .data() method needed

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following  `getElementsByTagName("p")[0]` and `getElementById("demo")` access the same element.

Both of the following work, so I can't figure out why the jquery data function is even needed. Is the second not portable to all browsers.

```
$(document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0]).data("funcZ", function() {console.log("ZZZZZ")})

$(document.getElementById("demo")).data("funcZ")()
```

---

```
document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].funcX = function() {console.log("XXXXX")}

document.getElementById("demo").funcX()
```

Comment: Data is a safer way to make sure you aren't overwriting an element's properties. Like if you wanted to put something into `href` or `target` for instance, you might override default attributes.

Comment: You could still override properties set through data().  And who would use a built in attribute like that except through sheer ignorance.

Comment: Hahaha, if you've spent enough time debugging DOM problems here on SO you'll have seen it happen all too often, the bit about ignorance might still apply most of the time though not always.

Comment: I'm trying to take a face value that that's the only reason, but I'm thinking there must be another reason as well.

Comment: Just quoting from "JS - The Definitive Guide" (p. 536):  "jQuery defines a getter/setter method named data() that sets or queries data associated with any document element or with the Document or Window objects. The ability to associate data with any element is an important and powerful one...".  But as I say, it seems like one can already do this in the DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According the the jQuery website:

> The jQuery.data() method allows us to attach data of any type to DOM elements in a way that is safe from circular references and therefore free from memory leaks. jQuery ensures that the data is removed when DOM elements are removed via jQuery methods, and when the user leaves the page.

It's possible that by attaching random fields to a DOM element, when the DOM element disappears, the fields remain in memory. It looks like jQuery handles that for you.

Comment: The *"free from memory leaks"* language should include some caveats. It's free from leaks *as long as* you only use jQuery methods to remove the elements. Otherwise, the memory leaks are very real, and perhaps worse.

Comment: As it happens, I had read that before posting the question.  Is there an actual example of a "circular reference" just using the DOM that data() prevents.  It all seems a little vague.  I guess my question really was, "Do seasoned JS programmers ONLY uses data() for some compelling reason, and would never set element properties directly as I've done above?

Comment: Also, surely the DOM and JS garbage collect in the example you gave. That's not a "circular reference" as such (Though will have to google "circular reference" and the DOM to find out what specifically that means here.)

Comment: OK,  it seems apparently the problem is with old version of IE, which do have problems with circular references and don't garbage collect them, e.g. if funcX above had instead pointed to a JS object which itself referenced the DOM element to which funcX had been assigned. (http://javascript.crockford.com/memory/leak.html)

Answer (score 0):

The `$.data()` method is perfect for hiding data as opposed to attaching it to a data-attribute. It's easily accessed by key/value, great for storing state information when creating plugins, or really anything.

Comment: But its not hidng key/values set using data() is it?